# looking to know how to convert non-Python expressions into Python expressions

Tags: python

How do i Convert each of the following (non-Python) expressions into Python expressions

3x

3x + y

x is evenly divisible by 12

x plus 7 is more than 100 or else x is less than fifty

Answer (score 1):

You can **model** them with `lambda` (anonymous functions) expressions or actual function definitions.

Example: `3x` is a statement that for every x returns 3 times it's value:

```
x_times_three = lambda x: x * 3
x_times_three(9) # 27
```

Using a function that would be:

```
def x_times_three(x):
    return x * 3
```

The others using lambdas:

```
# 3x + y
lambda x,y: 3*x + y


# x is evenly divisible by 12
lambda x: x % 12 == 0


# x plus 7 is more than 100 or else x is less than fifty
lambda x: (x + 7) > 100 or (x < 50)
```

Answer (score -1):

Convert the (non-Python) expressions into Python expressions:
x plus 7 is less than 100, else x is smaller than fifty

Comment: please can you add example.